# Can all real numbers be presented via a natural number and a sequence in the following way?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, definition, real-numbers

Is there (for each fixed base system with digits $0,1,\dots,m$) and then for each real number $r\in\mathbb R$, an integer $n\in\mathbb Z$ and a sequence $(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $a_i\in\{0,1,\dots,m\}$, such that

$$r=n\cdot 0.a_1a_2a_3\dots$$

and $|n|$ is minimal among all such representations? How to compute it (up to arbitrary precision)?

Intuitively I'd say the answer is yes (apart from maybe pathologies involving signs, zero or one, which I forget) but I'm not acquainted with methods to properly show this. The question came up when thinking about [definable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definable_real_number) and [computable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computable_number) real numbers and what it *really* means to work with non-compact manifolds on a computer or even on paper.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If $r=0$ let $n=0$; then you can take any digit sequence $(a_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$.
Otherwise, if $r\ne 0$ let $k=\bigl\lceil \strut|r|\bigr\rceil$ and the $n=\operatorname{sgn} (r) k$. Then the number $\frac{r}{n}$ is in $(0,1]$ and can be represented as requested.

Comment: What is $||r||$?

Comment: Why this $n$ is of minimal absolute value?